# WYSIWYG Texteditor Image Delete/Upload Logic

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, wysiwyg, summernote

Im using laravel with summernote wysiwyg text editor. I want user to be able to insert images to the text.

First i tried using the default summernote upload method. Basically it turns upload image to a base64 data url. Then after posting it, in a controller, that base64 is decoded into an actual image, saved to the server, and the img that src part is turned into a public image url that leads to the current server.

This worked fine with small images. But it didn't work well with big images. Post didn't work and i didn't get any error from anywhere. I assumed that it was because of the base64 part. I also saw [THIS THREAD](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1713) which made me wanna change base64 part even more.

So i switched to using onImageUpload callback without even thinking about it much. I saw lots of tutorials suggesting it.

With this callback, whenever user insert a image to the editor (before the post), OnImageUpload function is called in js. In that function, ajax sends to image to the controller, controller saves the image to the server and responds with its public url. Finally editor uses that url to show the image in the editor.

## Issue starts here with deleting images.

There is a OnMediaDelete function which has issues. It does not work with delete/backspace key for example. And even if that worked properly, **a user can insert pictures and leave the page (or use one bugs of the onMediaDelete callback) which means there isn't a easy way to determine if the uploaded image is actually used in a text or not.** Server would be filled with unused images?

How do you deal with this? Should i upload the images to a temp file during the editing and carry them to a actual folder if there are being used after the post? This would require stuff like cron to keep temp folder empty won't it? Is this how people deal with this?

Or should i just disable uploading images with text editor? Maybe a small content management for images in another part of the server?

Whole thing feels so simple but i am really struggling with it. I feel like i am missing a huge point here. Please help me. Sorry for this weird question. Thank you

Comment: I can think of no alternatives besides CRON. There is even [functionality](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) for it in Laravel.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?